# Pods are stuck in Init and Terminating state on single node on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

We have some pods randomly get stuck in Init state. When describing those pods we see that the init container is Running but it is not marked as Ready. Also the logs don't show any errors for the init container.

```
Init Containers:
  istio-init:
    Container ID:  <id>
    Image:         docker.io/istio/proxy_init:1.0.0
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://istio/proxy_init@sha256:345c40053b53b7cc70d12fb94379e5aa0befd979a99db80833cde671bd1f9fad
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Args:
      -p
      15001
      -u
      1337
      -m
      REDIRECT
      -i
      10.16.0.0/14,10.0.0.0/20
      -x

      -b
      4000,
      -d

    State:          Running                          <---
      Started:      Wed, 08 Jul 2020 10:35:52 +0200
    Ready:          False                            <---
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:         <none>
```

The app containers are in Waiting state with reason PodInitializing.

```
Containers:
  app:
    Container ID:
    Port:           4000/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting         <---
      Reason:       PodInitializing <---
    Ready:          False           <---
```

At first we assumed that something is up with the init container, however it doesn't seem that way. Later we concluded that all pods which are stuck in Init state are on the same node. That explains the randomness of this issue.

Does anyone have any advice with this sort of issue?

Thank you,

Marko

Comment: check the nodes status using `kubectl get nodes` and verify the kubelet service is running fine on that node. This will give you more insight on the issue.

Comment: Just checked the kubelet logs and turns out we have a lot of `container istio-init: selfLink was empty, can't make reference` logs. Even for some recently deleted pods.

Comment: does the node show the status as `Ready`? We need to identify the issue being caused by istio by looking at the historic logs. Any logging tool might help in this scenario. If none, try Datadog free trial for 14 days.

Comment: Yes. The status for that Node is Ready.

Comment: add the deployment yamls

Comment: Please provide more details. What version of GKE are you using. Its Istio addon on GKE or did you deployed it separately (what Istio version in this case)? Please specify what machine type did you use in your GKE cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your initContainer is running and your regular container is in 'waiting' state it means that the initContainer is not exiting. From that perspective, it makes sense due to the fact that initContainers are supposed to [exit/complete](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/#understanding-init-containers) and allow the regular container to start afterward. You should see something like this:

```yaml
Init Containers:
  istio-init:
    Container ID:  docker://bef731eae1eb3b6c9d926cacb497bb39a7d9796db49cd14a63014fc1a177d95b
    Image:         docker.io/istio/proxy_init:1.0.2
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://docker.io/istio/proxy_init@sha256:e16a0746f46cd45a9f63c27b9e09daff5432e33a2d80c8cc0956d7d63e2f9185
    .....
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
    .....
    Ready:          True
```

So looks like `docker.io/istio/proxy_init:1.0.0` is not exiting in your case. I would check the logs:

```sh
kubectl logs <pod-name> -c istio-init
```

It could be that you have something unique issue in that node. Maybe your networking is not working(?), maybe your network overlay process has problems(?), are all the components from your [Istio control plane](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/deployment/architecture/) up and running(?), etc.

Looks like [proxy_init](https://hub.docker.com/layers/istio/proxy_init/1.3.5-distroless/images/sha256-563936f73a4b6fb56672cd619049d7ff6e15a10c5e6fab0cf62499417547270d?context=explore) container runs an [istio-iptables](https://github.com/istio/cni/blob/master/tools/packaging/common/istio-iptables.sh) script. You could also try changing that container/script to get more debug info if you'd like to pinpoint the exact problem.

Comment: Hey Rico, after more investigation we have concluded that this issue was present on only one node out of 9. We have fixed the issue by adding a new one node, draining the broken one and then deleting it. Thank you for the help!